# Replace string in all columns of a SQLite database using one simple query

Tags: sqlite, replace, sql-update

Is it possible to replace a given string in all columns of a SQLite database using one simple query?

Let's say I have a table with the four columns name, age, income and friends:

```
+------+-----+--------+---------+
| name | age | income | friends |
+------+-----+--------+---------+
| John | 20  | 10     | 0       |
+------+-----+--------+---------+
| Jane | 25  | 20     | 0       |
+------+-----+--------+---------+
| June | 20  | 40     | 20      |
+------+-----+--------+---------+
```

And I want to replace all instances of "20" with "40" in the whole table using one simple query. Something like:

```
UPDATE table SET ALL-COLUMNS = 40 WHERE ALL-COLUMNS = 20
```

Is this possible to achieve using SQLite? Or do I have to create one query for each column?

```
UPDATE table SET age = 40 WHERE age = 20
UPDATE table SET income = 40 WHERE income = 20
UPDATE table SET friends = 40 WHERE friends = 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using three UPDATE statements is the simplest solution.

It would be possible to use a single UPDATE statement by using [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET age     = CASE age     WHEN 20 THEN 40 ELSE age     END,
    income  = CASE income  WHEN 20 THEN 40 ELSE income  END,
    friends = CASE friends WHEN 20 THEN 40 ELSE friends END
WHERE age = 20
   OR income = 20
   OR friends = 20
```